# Elementor Single Post Template does not apply to primary category

Tags: wordpress, elementor, posts, yoast

I have this website where I use the Elementor Single Post template to assign different layouts based on the primary category of the post (by primary category, I mean using Yoast). It works fine if the post has only one category. However, if the post has multiple categories, Elementor ignores the primary category set in the post and instead, shows the layout from the last category selected.

Example:

[image: img]

This post has 3 categories associated with it and each category has its own layout/template. I wanted the post to have the layout from Pavage since it's the primary category. However, it shows the layout of Paysagistes.

I have not tried anything yet as I have no clue what to do, or what to change. Please help!